# Use a 3d array on a function (array that contains arrays that contain strings)

Tags: c

I am making a program for the school that must generate 1 million strings all different from each other and whose length varies from 3 to 20 characters, I immediately want to say that I have already finished the program and I have already generated the strings, but I wanted to, as a pastime, optimize it.
I initially conceived it by making a 2d array (array containing char arrays) and it worked but I wanted to make the string checking faster by saving each string in the column equal to its length, for example the string "Ci_3sa" which contains 6 characters is stored in `arr[6][0][nOfChars]` and instead a 4 characters long word in `arr[4][0][nOfChars]`, I think I explained what I wanted to do .
I do not think I have made reference errors of the type of variables, because when I compile the code I do not get errors or warnings (I have active warnings), but when I execute the code it gives me an error in the dump core, I also tried to run the code in a debugger for C but however I don't understand what the problem is because it seems to work some times and in others it doesn't (but it never finished executing the program).
I would really like to understand what kind of mistake I made.

**I assume the error is in the "checkStrings()" function**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N_STRINGS 1000000
#define MIN_CHARS 3
#define MAX_CHARS 20

#define ASCII_START 32 // 32 è lo spazio
#define ASCII_END 126

#define randnum(min, max) ((rand() % (int)(((max) + 1) - (min))) + (min))

char *generateRandomString(int size)
{
    int i;
    // char *charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-#'?!";
    //  printf("Dimensione del charset: %ld\n", strlen(charset));
    char *res = malloc(size + 1);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        /*
        int key = randnum(0, 69);
        res[i] = charset[key];
        */
        int key = (rand() % (ASCII_END - ASCII_START)) + ASCII_START;
        res[i] = (char)key;
        if (key == 92 || key == 32 || key == 34)
            i--;
    }
    res[i] = '\0';
    return res;
}

int checkStrings(char *strs[18][N_STRINGS], char *str, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        /*
        printf("Lunghezza stringa\n: %ld", strlen(str));
        printf("Vediamo : %s\n", str);

        printf("Parola Array in posizione %d: %s\n", i, strs[i]);
        printf("Parola Generata: %s\n", str);
        */
        if (strcmp(strs[strlen(str) - 3][i], str) == 0)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void wirteOutput(char *outputFile, char *strs[18][N_STRINGS], int *ss, int isJson)
{
    FILE *output;
    if ((output = fopen(outputFile, "w+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("errore nell'apertura del file output");
        exit(2);
    }

    if (isJson == 1)
        fprintf(output, "[\n"); // inizio array in json
    for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ss[j]; i++)
        {
            if (isJson == 1)
                if (i < ss[j] - 1)
                    fprintf(output, "\"%s\",\n", strs[j][i]);
                else
                    fprintf(output, "\"%s\"\n", strs[j][i]);
            else
                fprintf(output, "%s\n", strs[j][i]);
            // printf("i: %d\n", i);
        }
    }

    if (isJson == 1)
        fprintf(output, "]\n"); // fine array in json

    fclose(output);
}

int main()
{
    // printf("Questo è il char 32: '%c'\n\n", 32);
    srand(time(NULL));
    // printf("%d\n", randnum(1, 70));
    int percentage = 0;
    int sizes[18] = {0};

    char *strings[18][N_STRINGS];
    printf("Starting to generate random strings\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N_STRINGS; i++)
    {
        int n = randnum(MIN_CHARS, MAX_CHARS);
        // printf("Numero di lettere estratto: %d\n", n);
        char *str = generateRandomString(n);
        // printf("Parola generata: %s\n", str);
        // sleep(1);
        if (checkStrings(strings, str, sizes[strlen(str) - 3]) != 0)
        {
            // printf("find same word\n");
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            strings[strlen(str) - 3][i] = str;
            sizes[strlen(str) - 3]++;
        }
        // if (i >= 10000 && N_STRINGS % i == 0 && ((100 * i) / N_STRINGS) % 10 == 0)
        if (i >= (N_STRINGS / 100) && percentage != (100 * i) / N_STRINGS)
        {
            percentage = (100 * i) / N_STRINGS;
            fputs("\033[A\033[2K", stdout);
            rewind(stdout);
            printf("%d%%\n", percentage); // 1000 : 100 = i : x
        }
        // printf("Parola assegnata: %s\n", strings[i]);
    }
    wirteOutput("output2.json", strings, sizes, 1);
    wirteOutput("output2.txt", strings, sizes, 0);
    printf("End\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is my test code and @AndreaWenzel i tried your solution but after some attempts it works, but I don't understand how this 3d array should work because according to the logic of this code it should only write the strings that have been generated and instead it writes me in the file 1 or 2 strings and in the other cases (null) even if the code reaches the end by writing "End".

This is the file

```
(null)
Ji+]
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//#define N_STRINGS 1000000
#define N_STRINGS 100
#define MIN_CHARS 3
#define MAX_CHARS 20

#define ASCII_START 32 // 32 è lo spazio
#define ASCII_END 126

#define randnum(min, max) ((rand() % (int)(((max) + 1) - (min))) + (min))

char *generateRandomString(int size)
{
    int i;
    // char *charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-#'?!";
    //  printf("Dimensione del charset: %ld\n", strlen(charset));
    char *res = malloc(size + 1);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        /*
        int key = randnum(0, 69);
        res[i] = charset[key];
        */
        int key = (rand() % (ASCII_END - ASCII_START)) + ASCII_START;
        res[i] = (char)key;
        if (key == 92 || key == 32 || key == 34)
            i--;
    }
    res[i] = '\0';
    return res;
}

int checkStrings(char *strs[18][N_STRINGS], char *str, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Lunghezza stringa: %ld\n", strlen(str));
        // sleep(1);
        printf("Parola Array in posizione %d: %s\n", i, strs[strlen(str) - 3][i]);
        printf("Parola Generata: %s\n", str);

        if (strs[strlen(str) - 3][i] != NULL)
            if (strcmp(strs[strlen(str) - 3][i], str) == 0)
                return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void wirteOutput(char *outputFile, char *strs[18][N_STRINGS], int *ss, int isJson)
{
    FILE *output;
    if ((output = fopen(outputFile, "w+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("errore nell'apertura del file output");
        exit(2);
    }

    if (isJson == 1)
        fprintf(output, "[\n"); // inizio array in json
    for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ss[j]; i++)
        {
            if (isJson == 1)
                if (i < ss[j] - 1)
                    fprintf(output, "\"%s\",\n", strs[j][i]);
                else
                    fprintf(output, "\"%s\"\n", strs[j][i]);
            else
                fprintf(output, "%s\n", strs[j][i]);
            // printf("i: %d\n", i);
        }
    }

    if (isJson == 1)
        fprintf(output, "]\n"); // fine array in json

    fclose(output);
}

int main()
{
    // printf("Questo è il char 32: '%c'\n\n", 32);
    srand(time(NULL));
    // printf("%d\n", randnum(1, 70));
    int percentage = 0;
    int sizes[18] = {0};

    // char *strings[18][N_STRINGS];
    char *(*strings)[N_STRINGS];

    strings = malloc(18 * sizeof *strings);

    if (strings == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Starting to generate random strings\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N_STRINGS; i++)
    {
        int n = randnum(MIN_CHARS, MAX_CHARS);
        // printf("Numero di lettere estratto: %d\n", n);
        char *str = generateRandomString(n);
        // printf("Parola generata: %s\n", str);
        // sleep(1);
        if (checkStrings(strings, str, sizes[strlen(str) - 3]) != 0)
        {
            // printf("find same word\n");
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            strings[strlen(str) - 3][i] = str;
            sizes[strlen(str) - 3]++;
        }
        // if (i >= 10000 && N_STRINGS % i == 0 && ((100 * i) / N_STRINGS) % 10 == 0)
        if (i >= (N_STRINGS / 100) && percentage != (100 * i) / N_STRINGS)
        {
            percentage = (100 * i) / N_STRINGS;
            fputs("\033[A\033[2K", stdout);
            rewind(stdout);
            printf("%d%%\n", percentage); // 1000 : 100 = i : x
        }
        // printf("Parola assegnata: %s\n", strings[i]);
    }

    printf("Ecco quante parole sono state scritte\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        printf("%d\n", sizes[i]);

    // wirteOutput("output2.json", strings, sizes, 1);
    wirteOutput("output2.txt", strings, sizes, 0);
    printf("End\n");
    free(strings);
    return 0;
}
```

I fixed the core dump problem, apparently, but the thing that turns my nose up in any case is that, in the test code, cmq when the words are generated and there are no similar ones, it does not assign them because so many times it has happened that was going to check for more than one null value within the same word length section.

This is another test after the changes:
(N_STRINGS = 50)

```
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
1/E1-&E/3@K
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
@wLo!>p%QR|+bNUgs
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
x>KEeQ&tG[jgT9roWdt
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
```

Comment: Note that your question would have a higher chance of being upvoted if you provided a [mre] of the problem. See that link for advice on how to make the example "minimal".

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @AndreaWenzel Thank you very much but I need a large array 18 which each of the 18 allocations contains 1 million strings (T.T), maybe I expressed myself wrong

Comment: @AndreaWenzel Ahh it was you who deleted your answer, wow I got scared because I thought I deleted it by mistake xD

Comment: Why are you calling the function `sleep` in your code?

Comment: @AndreaWenzel it was to better see the results on the terminal now I take it off

Comment: Which compiler are you using? If you are using gcc or clang, I recommend that you compile your code with `-fsanitize=address,undefined`. I believe that this will reveal the problem more clearly, making debugging easier. As far as I can tell, you are dereferencing an uninitalized pointer.

Comment: It's a flag of GCC?

Comment: Side note: The line `printf("Lunghezza stringa: %ld\n", strlen(str));` will likely work on 64-bit Linux, but it not guaranteed to work on other platforms. For example, it will likely not work on Microsoft Windows. The function `strlen` will return a value of type `size_t`. The correct `printf` conversion format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`, not `%ld`.

Comment: @Mattia: Yes, `-fsanitize=address,undefined` is a command-line option for gcc.

Comment: Ah Sorry about strlen(), i'm working on a Linux vm so It's work fine 

Comment: Side note: If you want to optimize your algorithm, sorting into buckets according to length (as you are doing) does improve performance, but a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) would generally be more efficient. Even better for performance would be a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), but this would require significantly more space.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
char *strings[18][N_STRINGS];
```

in the function `main` will allocate `18 * 1000000 * sizeof(char*)` bytes on the stack, which is 144 MB on most platforms. This will likely cause a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow). For example, on Linux, a typical maximum stack size is 8 MB.

You should generally not allocate more than a few kilobytes on the stack. I suggest that you allocate the memory on the heap instead, using [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc):

```
char *(*strings)[N_STRINGS];

strings = malloc( 18 * sizeof *strings );

if ( strings == NULL )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

The pointer strings should behave like a [decayed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) 2D/3D array (depending on how you see it). This is because I selected the type of the pointer in such a way that it points to a sub-array as a whole, instead of a single element of the sub-array.

Don't forget to call [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) when you no longer need the memory, otherwise you will have a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Also, the line

```
strings[strlen(str) - 3][i] = str;
```

does not do what you want. This line should be the following:

```
strings[strlen(str)-3][sizes[strlen(str)-3]] = str;
```

After fixing these bugs, your program should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//#define N_STRINGS 1000000
#define N_STRINGS 100
#define MIN_CHARS 3
#define MAX_CHARS 20

#define ASCII_START 32 // 32 è lo spazio
#define ASCII_END 126

#define randnum(min, max) ((rand() % (int)(((max) + 1) - (min))) + (min))

char *generateRandomString(int size)
{
    int i;
    // char *charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-#'?!";
    //  printf("Dimensione del charset: %ld\n", strlen(charset));
    char *res = malloc(size + 1);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        /*
        int key = randnum(0, 69);
        res[i] = charset[key];
        */
        int key = (rand() % (ASCII_END - ASCII_START)) + ASCII_START;
        res[i] = (char)key;
        if (key == 92 || key == 32 || key == 34)
            i--;
    }
    res[i] = '\0';
    return res;
}

int checkStrings(char *strs[18][N_STRINGS], char *str, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Lunghezza stringa: %ld\n", strlen(str));
        // sleep(1);
        printf("Parola Array in posizione %d: %s\n", i, strs[strlen(str) - 3][i]);
        printf("Parola Generata: %s\n", str);

        if (strs[strlen(str) - 3][i] != NULL)
            if (strcmp(strs[strlen(str) - 3][i], str) == 0)
                return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void wirteOutput(char *outputFile, char *strs[18][N_STRINGS], int *ss, int isJson)
{
    FILE *output;
    if ((output = fopen(outputFile, "w+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("errore nell'apertura del file output");
        exit(2);
    }

    if (isJson == 1)
        fprintf(output, "[\n"); // inizio array in json
    for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ss[j]; i++)
        {
            if (isJson == 1)
                if (i < ss[j] - 1)
                    fprintf(output, "\"%s\",\n", strs[j][i]);
                else
                    fprintf(output, "\"%s\"\n", strs[j][i]);
            else
                fprintf(output, "%s\n", strs[j][i]);
            // printf("i: %d\n", i);
        }
    }

    if (isJson == 1)
        fprintf(output, "]\n"); // fine array in json

    fclose(output);
}

int main( void )
{
    // printf("Questo è il char 32: '%c'\n\n", 32);
    srand(time(NULL));
    // printf("%d\n", randnum(1, 70));
    int percentage = 0;
    int sizes[18] = {0};

    // char *strings[18][N_STRINGS];
    char *(*strings)[N_STRINGS];

    strings = malloc(18 * sizeof *strings);

    if (strings == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Starting to generate random strings\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N_STRINGS; i++)
    {
        int n = randnum(MIN_CHARS, MAX_CHARS);
        // printf("Numero di lettere estratto: %d\n", n);
        char *str = generateRandomString(n);
        // printf("Parola generata: %s\n", str);
        // sleep(1);
        if (checkStrings(strings, str, sizes[strlen(str) - 3]) != 0)
        {
            // printf("find same word\n");
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            strings[strlen(str)-3][sizes[strlen(str)-3]] = str;
            sizes[strlen(str) - 3]++;
        }
        // if (i >= 10000 && N_STRINGS % i == 0 && ((100 * i) / N_STRINGS) % 10 == 0)
        if (i >= (N_STRINGS / 100) && percentage != (100 * i) / N_STRINGS)
        {
            percentage = (100 * i) / N_STRINGS;
            fputs("\033[A\033[2K", stdout);
            rewind(stdout);
            printf("%d%%\n", percentage); // 1000 : 100 = i : x
        }
        // printf("Parola assegnata: %s\n", strings[i]);
    }

    printf("Ecco quante parole sono state scritte\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        printf("%d\n", sizes[i]);

    // wirteOutput("output2.json", strings, sizes, 1);
    wirteOutput("output2.txt", strings, sizes, 0);
    printf("End\n");
    free(strings);
    return 0;
}
```

This program writes the following to the file `output2.txt`:

```
ux*
&{;
)}I
XGo
LOh
V3)
8>q
GNX
@J7
^%|
-keU
m44T
_a;x
F*|+
w0nTc
21gMx
N>z/J
bWM|Y
@/=kr
ill&A
}MWQk
#6Ouab
ado8mR
mYtPO:
Ct?LJ,
QpC1=g
U+nF&*
oSQE+p
]N[TH(
'L_hwty
y{AGIR0
k>b5_Me4
(n2oQD$f
3>SKZ.?y
gb;gO,aq`
;mGV_joDp
pWF7A!3jK
$%ZD#l!4&
J?VFUI2gZ
X6{Z!Qs<5
`VMNvn[+B
+61rN2b0*S
w-4@8HV;!M
)dkU^(SD@:
@w;C%Xt-<N
Qz5+LLeN}u
Gzm1qCsy-=
Yyc3v}RW{=
B9-,q.A<ou
uv>m*`BQm5
Qsel*;+x'Y7
#0r;E7VMhKO
,G7pD^Z{OP%
ZiT2x:bI|d!
*koo)ltKdwO
%KI.9Zs}mDX
5Q}n77CU8$k
H@=KJQp=7v>
6*DvlN]NB6W
J^rM*$i:[9>(
7]jH@iP9|wg?
oS/-=,5->@^b
V8J@Y;Ks+qy6
jyt9c()ZNe1?
{&)tTLGH/%An
`eg}|ihyr_64
jS&>?p.X];y9=
{]KT&b1Au|(lk
]?d89=!^zZee^
Y&g[#,nX@]Rq#
'zh>xIXN?mMRf
Ycx2!-n@zVzDu
>cr@&g%:5@a%`
w-!#.ed4)[{Mk<
Vj{j-p#`8SqF#?+
5OHpfux>,1#9R6Z
EH*e`XWm%,&ak_5
*sm)N'IW{:?DbOd
;u-J;aDeR4J{GM=U
TE$i0Lv]V7%#T?pj
]Ed?tb#7!ham[:@m
Yi@m!Xr%Tfjzht+X
d7!#3SW@yt`&D,RsD
3R]/g$v5&`N{f}Ne)
@(UkF#8@9J*RvZ]1x
Afz(3;4S]PDJ3G|Sz
w#@--N.^i1q>h3:y/Z
&<-o46#<Z?&Vsd6Obf
l#&^KCK?*(*!cb<3(u
PuuU(]M:V?Q[C'zO-2
'cT-0aK5u!0&vimv(DY
gr9`t*6?QSK{%B[#gXg
UEsgt5IDL1^62g8K6+}
BEYRZfo?gn4+pJi!j>P
PN#26}M{dT`Txv[N|y)!
46p#AnR<>TP&OMGv35BE
ANZZ>;4D?S!}V):j/Cl<
7bqAwAu6rhY&'}:&:=4;
O:9HKA))>^=g+]?kNh9Q
!cX'f6Dr@9Ok#?|NV-1R
```

Note that this program has memory leaks, because you are not freeing any of the strings allocated in the function `generateRandomString`.

Also, in the function `main`, the expression `strlen(str)-3` is being used 4 times in total. Especially the call to the function `strlen` is rather expensive. Therefore, it would make sense to only call this function once and to save the result to a variable, so that you remember the result and don't have to call the function again.

Comment: But so it doesn't create me a 2d array?

Comment: @Mattia: I believe that I have now fixed my answer. Your code is still generating a segmentation fault, but as far as I can tell, that is due to another unreleated problem, which you should be able to diagnose in a debugger.

Comment: @AndreaWenzel I tried your solution but i don't understand if it's me or something is wrong with using 3d array, i updated my question

Comment: @Mattia: I am looking into it.

Comment: @Mattia: Your code seems to be assuming that the array content is zero-initialized. However, this is not the case in your original code, and it also is not the case when using `malloc`. If you want it to be zero-initalized, you can use [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) instead of `malloc`. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AndreaWenzel I tried even with calloc but it doesn't change

Comment: @Mattia: After further investigation, I found that the problem was not using `malloc` instead of `calloc`, as I claimed in my previous comment, but rather that the line `strings[strlen(str) - 3][i] = str;` was wrong. I have updated my answer.